# Custom group in PivotTable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vlookup, worksheet-function

I'd like to add a custom range group in a pivot table. For example in a table that reports on sales, I'd like to have columns with the following sales ranges:

```
$0      -  $24999
$25000  -  $74999
$75000  - $124999
$125000 - $249999
$250000 and over.
```

I suspect one way may be to add an extra column to my source data, but I can't work out a formula for the grouping. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a simple formula of the kind:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Bands,2)
```

copied down to suit (in the data source) though this requires a lookup table also (here named `Bands`):

[image: SO25273490 example]

which, if the named range is of workbook scope, need not be in the same sheet.

This way the bands are relatively easy to adjust, however irregular.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution - In your extra column, put in a formula with something along the lines of:

```
= ROUNDDOWN(Sales_Col_Value/25000,0)
```

That would make each $25k bracket go into 0, 1, etc...

Or, if you wanted it to be txt, you could do something like:

```
= "$" & (ROUNDDOWN(Sales_Col_Value/25000,0) * 25000) & " - " & "$" & (((ROUNDDOWN(Sales_Col_Value/25000,0) + 1) * 25000) - 1)
```

Hope that makes sense